# How to display/save a Layered graph in altair by running code from Python console

Tags: python-3.x, altair, datavisualization.toolkit

After creating three different charts with altair graph API and then merging them as per altair documentation.

(underlay+base+overlay).save("layeredChart.html")

An html file is generated with name layeredChart.html

On opening the html file error comes:

**JavaScript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector002_tuple"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.**

What can be the reason for error in html file generation with altair though works fine with jupyter notebook??

**Code**:

```
import altair as alt

#altair plot
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

#Selection tool
selection = alt.selection_single(fields = ['Country/Region'])

#Underlay
base = alt.Chart(de_long).mark_line(strokeWidth=4,opacity=0.7).encode(
    x = alt.X('Day'),
    y = alt.Y('De',scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
    color = alt.Color('Country/Region',legend=None)
    ).properties(
    width=800,
    height=650
    ).interactive()
print(alt.renderers.names())

#Chart
chart1 = base.encode(
    color=alt.condition(selection,'Country/Region:N',alt.value('lightgray'))).add_selection(selection)


#Overlay
overlay = base.encode(
    color = 'Country/Region',
    opacity = alt.value(0.5),
    tooltip = ['Country/Region:N','Name:N']
).transform_filter(selection)

finalChart = (base+chart1+overlay)
finalChart.save("final.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

This error generally means that you've called `add_selection()` with the same selection on multiple layers, which is not supported by the Vega-Lite renderer.

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this error:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(10)})
selection = alt.selection_single()
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(x='x').add_selection(selection)
base.mark_line() + base.mark_point()
```

```
Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector001_tuple"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

The way to fix it is to add the selection to only one of the layers; for example:

```
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(x='x')
base.mark_line() + base.mark_point().add_selection(selection)
```

[image]